# Ant Blackberry Build Fails

Tags: blackberry, ant

If I have small Blackberry project with just 10 or less java class files, and if I try to build it with ANT, then it works fine. But my actual Blackberry Project has more than 600 java classes in various packages. I get following Error while trying ANT.

“I/O Error: Cannot run program “java.exe”: CreateProcess error=87”

Comment: Could you please post more information?  It would be helpful to see your Ant script & the line number (if any) where the error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using [bb-ant-tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/main).  The [docs](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs) for the generatesourcelist attribute to the rapc ant task say

> Generate list of source files in text file. Set this to true when java returns "CreateProcess error=87" on Windows. Optional, defaults to false.

Comment: So what do we do if generatesourcelist isn't enough? Apparently, rapc accepts the source list, then reads all the files and delivers each one separately to javac on the commandline. Thus rather defeating the whole point of the process.

Comment: The point of using "generatesourcelist" is to keep the command line under the cmd.exe limit of 8192 characters.   It sounds like you may be running into a different issue.