# eclipse junit runner java createprocess error 87 the parameter is incorrect

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am working on a project, and have windows 7, 64 bit.  I am trying to help a coworker get setup to develop for this project.  She has a windows 7 64 bit machine as well.  On here machine, the application runs fine for the most part, we can load up the application in our Jetty 7 launch configuration, and works as expected.  However, when she tries to run any of the projects JUnit tests, she gets "java createprocess error 87 the parameter is incorrect".  We have verfied the project configurations are the same, the classpath and windows path are fine.  She has a slightly newer version of eclipse (Indigo) and Java 6 than I do.  Does anyone have any ideas on what could be going awry here?

Comment: workspace path too long as stated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970995/createprocess-error-87-the-parameter-is-incorrect

Comment: the workspace is c:\kc\project\  .... that isn't too long, is it?