# Get logs of what jenkins is doing

Tags: python, jenkins

I am completely new at jenkins. I installed the windows package and tried it out but I am a little lost.
Here is my issue. I basically need jenkins to run a python script located on my computer. It's a scipt that has 1 line

```
print("hello World")
```

I created a new build setup with the following under the Build Environment
"Execute windows batch command"

```
cd "C:\perforce\projects\DEV\E9318_SuperNova\P22_module_split_up\Ref\Tools\"
"C:\perforce\projects\DEV\E9318_SuperNova\P22_module_split_up\Ref\Tools\test.py"
```

The console output from the build

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\E9318_SuperNova-P22_Compensator_FPGA_PSA
[E9318_SuperNova-P22_Compensator_FPGA_PSA] $ cmd /c call C:\windows\TEMP\jenkins7605841087640242580.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\E9318_SuperNova-P22_Compensator_FPGA_PSA>cd "C:\perforce\projects\DEV\E9318_SuperNova\P22_module_split_up\Ref\Tools\" 

C:\perforce\projects\DEV\E9318_SuperNova\P22_module_split_up\Ref\Tools>"C:\perforce\projects\DEV\E9318_SuperNova\P22_module_split_up\Ref\Tools\test.py"

C:\perforce\projects\DEV\E9318_SuperNova\P22_module_split_up\Ref\Tools>exit 103 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated,
Thanks,
Amish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*.py` files don't seem to be executable directly (as invoked from a shell)
Change the second line of your script with :

```
"C:\path\to\python.exe" "C:\perforce\projects\DEV\E9318_SuperNova\P22_module_split_up\Ref\Tools\test.py"
```

Anyway, this form field is expecting the path to a script that makes the build and runs the tests.

Comment: but python.exe is in the windows path, is the jenkins path different

Comment: Being in the Windows PATH does not imply that Jenkins "knows" this "test.py" is supposed to be executed by some python.exe. Did you test the suggested solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I will also refer to
[How to set the PATH environment variable in Jenkins configuration on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473479/how-to-set-the-path-environment-variable-in-jenkins-configuration-on-windows) as a possible solution. After I added the python executable path to the node's path, I could call my script using
    python.exe "C:\perforce\projects\DEV\E9318_SuperNova\P22_module_split_up\Ref\Tools\test.py"