# Jenkins slave path not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

seeing this: [How to set the PATH environment variable in Jenkins configuration on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473479/how-to-set-the-path-environment-variable-in-jenkins-configuration-on-windows)

I set my path on my windows slave like this:
[image]

Then tried running this in a pipeline:

```
sh script: "echo sdfsdfsdf"
```

And I get error:

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

EDIT:
OK something weird is happening and I dont understand this behavior.
I added "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\" to the system path on the slave directly and restarted agent then this started working:

```
sh script: "echo sdfsdfsdf"
```

But this threw "cmd.exe" not found:

```
bat script: "echo sdfsdfsdf"
```

Then I removed the Path env from the slave and now BOTH work.

So that setting on the slave was doing something, what? I have no idea. Really like to just use that setting instead of having an external slave config like this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reconnect your agent after setting the path? This is required.

Furthermore: Not sure whether Jenkins understands Windows environment variables notation.
Use `${Path};C:\Program Files\Git\bin`