# Add Python path to Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm facing an issue in adding Python path to Jenkins which I've set up locally on my windows machine. I have added the path in the environment i.e **Jenkins-->Manage Jenkins-->Global Tool Configuration**. Attached is the image for the error that I'm getting.

[image]

The plugin for this Python binding that I've used is Shining Panda.

Comment: Did you the check the answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473479/how-to-set-the-path-environment-variable-in-jenkins-configuration-on-windows/36502958 ?

Comment: Your PATH should contain directories, not individual executables. There should be no spaces between the entries.