# Jenkins build failed due to command not being recognized

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, command, pandoc

I have this build error saying pandoc command is not recognize, when I build my pipeline on Jenkins :
[image]

But when I run the exact same command using cmd.exe from the same repository it works perfectly :

[image]

So what's wrong here, my command pandoc is well installed and can perfectly be used from cmd.exe, why doesn't it works from Jenkins ?

Here is my Jenkins code (the part causing the error is in the "Build" stage):

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Prerequisites') {
            steps {
                //bat 'RMDIR C:\\wamp64\\www\\html\\doc'
                bat 'MKDIR C:\\wamp64\\www\\html\\doc'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                bat 'pandoc -s C:\\wamp64\\www\\index.md -o C:\\wamp64\\www\\index.html'
                bat 'pandoc -s C:\\wamp64\\www\\index.md -o C:\\wamp64\\www\\index.docx'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                bat 'COPY C:\\wamp64\\www\\index.html COPY C:\\wamp64\\www\\html\\index.html'
                bat 'COPY C:\\wamp64\\www\\index.docx COPY C:\\wamp64\\www\\html\\doc\\index.docx'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins doesn't automatically take your Windows (path) environment variables. Instead, what you need to do is to go to `Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties -> Environment variables` and add a new variable called `Path`. For the value, set `$Path`, and your path variables should start getting registered.

The issue has been discussed extensively in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36473479/3730626).

Comment: I tried it, and now the build fails from the beginning at my first batch command, error is : "cmd is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."