# Error using pipenv in jenkins pipeline on windows

Tags: jenkins, pipenv

```
10:27:55  pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
10:27:55  Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I am getting this error when using pipenv on a jenkins build. I have verified that my path is correct by manually setting the path and also setting the path on my jenkins build. Is there still something I am missing or has anyone else ran into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36473479/3730626), which has a similar problem. The solution is to create a global environment variable called `Path` and assign your windows `$PATH` into it followed by the path to pipenv. This allows Jenkins to properly identify the binary.